# hibernate and java properties

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, javafx-8

As i´m really new to hibernate (never used it) and i´d like to give it a try in combination with mysql there is one thing that seems to me as i could´t use hibernate:

I saw many examples of POJOs which are used with hibernate that all use

> ... implements Serializable

If a, let´s call it "hibernate POJO class" has to implement Serializable the new java properties and binding mechanism can´t be used because of not being serializable as i read somewhere else.

So the question is:
Could one not use properties API with hibernate POJOs?

Maybe i misunderstood something but then one could help me :)

Thx
Ingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom serialized form and just serialize the value held by the property:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private transient StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeObject(getName());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty((String) s.readObject());
    }
}
```

You can read more on the JPA aspect of this topic in [this blog](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html) and [this blog](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/).